# Do 'new knowledge / old fact' replies to Jackson's Knowledge Argument imply their converse?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, knowledge

The various 'new knowledge /old facts' replies to Frank Jackson's '[Knowledge Argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia-knowledge/#NewKnowFactView)' are among the most widely held (or, at least, the most thoroughly debated.) They claim that while its subject, Mary, gains new knowledge on first seeing colors, it is only of facts that she already knew, though now under another conceptualization (or seen in a new guise, as Torin Alter puts it.)

Furthermore, for this to be a challenge to the knowledge argument, it seems that the facts in question must be among those that Mary has learned through her study of everything that physics could possibly know about color vision, for if they are not in that set, they would not present a challenge to Jackson's claims. As the linked article says, "but the facts that make these new items of knowledge true are *physical facts that Mary knew before release* under another conceptualization" [my emphasis], and the only physical facts we know she had, at that time, were those learned from her studies.

A 'new knowledge/old fact' reply defines a certain subset of physical facts -- the set of old facts that she now knows in a new guise -- and claims that these facts are both necessary and sufficient to account for Mary's newly-acquired knowledge of what it is like to see colors.

Now, if one accepts an argument of this form, is one not tacitly (or perhaps explicitly) also accepting, as a corollary, the converse: that in knowing what it is like to see colors, one also knows the above-mentioned subset of physical facts, albeit in a different guise? Including, I would think, some facts which are not yet explicitly known to physics, as if they were, then presumably the knowledge argument could be definitively refuted by making use of those facts in an explanation of why it is wrong.

Would it not also follow that even if Mary had not studied at all, she would still end up knowing all these physical facts, once she had seen colors?

If a new knowledge / old fact argument is correct, but the above converse is not, then would that not imply at least two different ways to know what it is like to see colors: the way that Mary knows, and the way that the rest of us do? On the other hand, if one accepts both, then how could one account for Mary's physical knowledge evidently being propositional (having been learned from books or lectures), while that of the rest of us apparently is not?

I am not asking whether this is a reasonable position to hold, but merely whether it is a corollary of 'new knowledge/old fact' responses. Nor am I asking whether the knowledge argument succeeds in making its case, or whether it is a good argument.

**Update**: To clarify what I am asking, I have set out the central argument as a sequence of premises:

Premise 1: According to the 'new knowledge/old facts' reply to Jackson's knowledge argument, there is a certain set of physical facts that a) she already knows, from her studies; and b) when Mary first sees colors, she gets to know in a new guise.

Premise 2: According to this reply, it is a) necessary, and b) sufficient, that Mary knows these particular physical facts in order for her to know what she learned on release. (Justification: a) If there are any facts that are not necessary, we can remove them, and their corresponding new knowledge, from the reply to Jackson. b) If they are not sufficient to account for everything Mary learns from seeing colors, the reply fails as a challenge to the knowledge argument, as some of what Mary learns on her release is not covered by this reply.)

Premise 3: If Mary had studied nothing during her isolation and knew nothing of physics, she would still gain the same knowledge of what it is like to see colors, after being allowed to see some. This would be so even in a time when no-one knew any physics.

Conclusion 1: According to this reply, even if Mary had studied nothing during her isolation and knew nothing of physics prior to release, she would, after her color experiences, know the set of facts defined in premise 1.

Conlusion 2: According to this reply, anyone, who has come to know what it is like to see colors, has, by so doing, learned all the corresponding physical facts (as defined in premise 1), even if they are not known to science at that time.

I suppose one might take the position that any physical state that obtains is a physical fact, regardless of whether anyone knows it or has thought a proposition stating it, but this would not be relevant to the 'new knowledge / old fact' reply, as the old facts being considered are limited to those which Mary could learn through books, lectures or some other form of discourse.

Comment: *Some* of the facts, certainly, but why *all* of them? The "all there is to know physically" is the premise of Jackson's own argument, and a pretty unrealistic "for the sake of the argument" one at that. But  regardless, there are certainly infinitely many different conceptual ways to know physical facts. Just take wave mechanics and matrix mechanics versions of quantum mechanics, for example, or various equivalent formulations of string theory that look nothing alike.

Comment: @Conifold Even Jackson does not posit that Mary knows every physical fact, only(!) those that are at all relevant to what she learns after her release. Given any particular argument of this form, and Mary's mental state at a given time after her release (and therefore after a specific sequence of color-vision experiences), does the theory behind that specific argument not pick out a specific set of physical facts, being just those that she now knows under a new guise as a consequence of her experience? According to that theory, anyone with the same knowledge would know all these facts, no?

Comment: Your phrasing is a little hard to parse, but sure, one learns some (fragmented) set of physical facts from phenomenal experience with colors. For example, one learns that red is different from green, something that can be alternatively conceptualized in terms of spectral frequency. It may even be the case that in order to match all "relevant" phenomenal knowledge theoretically one has to learn theories that then imply vastly more than the underlying initial facts.

Comment: @Conifold I agree that one _might_ learn that the difference that you have experienced, between red and green, is a consequence of different frequencies, but if, according to a 'new knowledge/old fact' theory, this is one of the facts that Mary comes to know in a new guise when she learns what it is like to distinguish red from green, then does it not follow (from this theory) that whenever someone learns what it is like to make that distinction, they _must_ have come to know the corresponding physical theory, if not beforehand, then at that moment?

Comment: No, it does not. Just because I learn *all* of wave mechanics, which already expresses all the facts of matrix mechanics as well, does not mean that I know *any* matrix mechanics. Or simpler, *all* facts of Peano arithmetic are already conceptualized in its axioms. But it does not mean that those familiar with the axioms know if the twin prime conjecture is true. Theoretical knowledge is a lot more than the underlying facts, or even the underlying facts combined with accompanying skills and feelings.

Comment: @Conifold I agree, but what I am asking about is what is implied by the 'new knowledge/old fact' responses, and to be clear, what I mean by 'theory' in the above is whatever theory about the mind underlies the specific 'new knowledge/old fact' argument being considered. I did not make it clear, but I see this 'conversely' argument as potentially a challenge to all 'new knowledge/old fact' responses to Jackson. FWIW, I also did not make it clear that I think the knowledge argument fails to make its case, but not for 'new knowledge/old fact' reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104732/discussion-between-a-raybould-and-conifold).

Comment: Sorry, but at this point I do not see why it is a challenge. Our ability to judge a face on a drawing as "sad" is certainly based on information contained in the matrix of pixels, even though it would be fiendishly difficult to program a computer to reproduce the skill. I think Jackson's argument fails for exactly this reason, he  implicitly relies on logical omnisience about knowledge, and underestimates the gap between depth and surface information. A very common vice of knowledge theories from 50-s to 80-s.

Comment: Your mistake is in premise 2. Why do you think these are necessary and sufficient for each other? The whole point of the 'old fact' reply is that knowing under one guise is not sufficient for knowing under a different guise.

Comment: @Eliran I have updated the justification section of the 2nd. paragraph to make it clear (I hope) in what sense it is sufficient: it does not leave anything unexplained (if it is correct). The 'necessary' claim is simply that we can elininate anything that is redundant. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.